# get new package version in vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to build a project with cmake und vcpkg but the vcpkg won't install the new version of the fmt library (10.1.1). There must be a file where the to be installed version is defined(?)

```
The following packages will be built and installed:
[...]
> [CMake]     fmt:x64-windows@8.1.1#1 -- C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\fmt\602d9743b7957c9e82a06d0e81d58637c6df5222
[...]
```

`vcpkg.json`

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version-string": "5",
    "builtin-baseline": "c6a4ed75f03a7485cf6fc91794809cd73f8f5aeb",
    "dependencies": [
        "cereal",
        "eigen3",
        "fast-float",
        "fmt",
        "gtest",
        "magic-enum",
        "ms-gsl",
        "nlopt",
        "spdlog"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by updating the `builtin-baseline` via `vcpkg x-update-baseline`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you installed vcpkg via git, change to the vcpkg installation directory (`cd c:\vcpkg`) and use `git pull` to update the portfiles.

When you re-build your project, vcpkg should now pick up the new version of the library.

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: @Nick Can you elaborate? What does "doesn't work" mean? Also, could you add information about your build process? Perhaps you just need to reconfigure make. Could you try ``cmake .`` in your build directory?

Comment: of cause. I did the `pull` but cmake still uses version 8.1.1 and I am using `Delete cache and Reconfigure` so it generates again